# Error setting a style in code for the HintStyle on the PhoneTextBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For various reasons I am trying to create and set a style in code, but I am getting the following Application Unhandled Exception.

```
$exception  {System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.EntryRenderer.GetDesiredSize(Double widthConstraint, Double    heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.Platform.GetNativeSize(VisualElement view, Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint)
   at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.SumOfSizeRequests(Double widthConstraint, Double heightConstraint, Int32& numOfExpanders)
   at Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutChildren(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeAllocated(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnChildMeasureInvalidated(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InvalidateMeasure()
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.NativeSizeChanged()
   at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_IsNativeStateConsistent(Boolean value)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinPhone.VisualElementRenderer`2.<SetNativeControl>b__1(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)} System.Exception
```

The code I have written is

```cs
var hintStyle = new Style(typeof(PhoneTextBox));
hintStyle.Setters.Add(
   new Setter(
              System.Windows.Controls.Control.ForegroundProperty,
              view.PlaceholderTextColor.ToBrush())
              );
phoneTextBox.HintStyle = hintStyle;
```

This runs without error, but at some point later (I assume at some rendering point) the error occurs. There is a complication in that this is in a Xamarin Forms Renderer.

My objective is just to be able to change the Hint colour. Any ideas how I could make this work or use another method?

Comment: Are you wanting to change the foreground text color for **WindowsPhone** implementation of **SearchBar**?  If not, what control are you wanting to change the appearance of?

Comment: No this is to change the Hint text color. However the control is the Windows PhoneToolkit PhoneTextBox. This has a property called HintStyle which takes a Style object. Now that you have asked, I can see that the Styles TargetType should be ContentControl not PhoneTextBox. That's sorted it...thanks for making me check ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment above made me double check my code and noticed that the Styles TargetType was incorrect. The correct target type is ContentControl and the corrected code is

```cs
var hintStyle = new Style(typeof(ContentControl));
hintStyle.Setters.Add(
   new Setter(
          System.Windows.Controls.Control.ForegroundProperty,
          view.PlaceholderTextColor.ToBrush())
          );
phoneTextBox.HintStyle = hintStyle;
```

Lesson here is always make sure you have the correct TargetType and having none will also error in a unhelpful way!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message and for me the reason was that the Xamarin.Forms package wasn't properly installed for my Windows Phone project. After searching for hours  I reinstalled it via NuGet and it worked.

I know this is not the solution for this specific problem (as it is already solved) but this was the first thread I found when searching for a solution to my problem. Hope it helps someone.